# spring beans and sessionFactory in different xml files

Tags: spring, configuration

We have 3 applications using 3 different spring configuration files. But we have one database and one datasource, so one session factory.Hhow can we import the session factory bean into the 3 different spring config files?

Answer (score 4):

Configure your SessionFactory in a single XML file and import this configuration into whichever applications' Spring contexts need it.

If you use classpath-based importing like this:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:path/to/session-factory-beans.xml"/>
    <... other bean definitions.../>
</beans>
```

Then your distribution mechanism is pretty flexible, since the classloader will resolve the resource for you. You could

- copy session-factory-beans.xml into each project that requires it, or
- add it to a jarfile and share that amongst the applications, or
- add it to shared/classes if the applications are all running inside the same application server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XML configuration:

Put your database settings in a Spring configuration called "database-config.xml" and import it in the other configuration files.

```
<import resource="database-config.xml"/>
```

As to how you share it among three applications is more of a Configuration Management issue. You could use ant / maven to check it out of a repository and move it into the correct location.